# Finding all "Non-Binary" files

Tags: files, find, text, newlines

Is it possible to use the `find` command to find all the "non-binary" files in a directory?  Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

I've received an archive of files from a windows user.  This archive contains source code and image files.  Our build system doesn't play nice with files that have windows line endings.  I have a command line program (`flip -u`) that will flip line endings between *nix and windows.  So, I'd like to do something like this

```
find . -type f | xargs flip -u
```

However, if this command is run against an image file, or other binary media file, it will corrupt the file.  I realize I could build a list of file extensions and filter with that, but I'd rather have something that's not reliant on me keeping that list up to date.

So, is there a way to find all the non-binary files in a directory tree?  Or is there an alternate solution I should consider?

Comment: You could use the `file` utility somewhere in your script/pipeline to identify whether the file is data or text

Comment: What do you mean by non-binary (everything on a modern computer is binary). I am guessing you are using the distinction from the old C/PM operating system, that had text and binary files. Text files could be of any length but had to end with a ctrl-z, and binary files had to be a multiple of a 512byte block. If so you are meaning text file. (I also note that you write about line ending in non-binary files, this also would suggest that they are text files) Is this correct?

Comment: All files are binary, it is just a mater of interpretation. Are you asking for how to find text files?

Comment: @richard I come form an era where we called files meant to be interpreted as plain-text *plain text*, and all other files (images, word processing docs, etc.) binary.  I know its all just one's and zeros under the hood :)

Comment: @AlanStorm yes CPM had that concept of binary and text (but not binary and non-binary). Binary files had a size multiple of one disk block, and textfiles ended with a ctrl-z (EOF), so could not include this elsewhere. Later Microsoft did the popular cheap clone of CPM and fixed this limitation, but kept the idea, they then did a `\n` → `\r\n` conversion when saving a file. I don't know why they did this, it causes no end of trouble.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean about my terms -- I'll use binary/text in the future to avoid confusion. Re: the \r\n thing -- its my understand those are the ASCII characters for a typewriter's carriage return (move to the beginning of the line) and line feed (move down one line).  So \r\n is a "more accurate" model of the real world physical thing an end of line character was for.  Pre OS X, Macs used just a \r for this.  I usually write the whole thing off as "arbitrary choices made in a rush that we're still dealing with"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd use `file` and pipe the output into grep or awk to find text files, then extract just the filename portion of `file`'s output and pipe that into xargs.

something like:

```
file * | awk -F: '/ASCII text/ {print $1}' | xargs -d'\n' -r flip -u
```

Note that the grep searches for 'ASCII text' rather than any just 'text' - you probably don't want to mess with Rich Text documents or unicode text files etc.

You can also use `find` (or whatever) to generate a list of files to examine with `file`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec file {} + | \
  awk -F: '/ASCII text/ {print $1}' | xargs -d'\n' -r flip -u
```

The `-d'\n'` argument to xargs makes xargs treat each input line as a separate argument, thus catering for filenames with spaces and other problematic characters.  i.e. it's an alternative to `xargs -0` when the input source doesn't or can't generate NULL-separated output (such as `find`'s `-print0` option).  According to the changelog, xargs got the `-d`/`--delimiter` option in Sep 2005 so should be in any non-ancient linux distro (I wasn't sure, which is why I checked - I just vaguely remembered it was a "recent" addition).

Note that a linefeed is a valid character in filenames, so this will break if any filenames have linefeeds in them.  For typical unix users, this is pathologically insane, but isn't unheard of if the files originated on Mac or Windows machines.

Also note that `file` is not perfect.  It's very good at detecting the type of data in a file but can occasionally get confused.

I have used numerous variations of this method many times in the past with success.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! For some reason `file` displays `English text` rather than `ASCII text` on my Solaris system, so I modified that portion accordingly. Also, I replaced `awk -F: '{print $1}'` with the equivalent `cut -f1 -d:`.

Comment: worth saying `grep -I` filters binaries

Comment: Looking for the word `text` should be sufficient.  This will also pick up `file` descriptions like `ASCII Java program text` or `HTML document text` or `troff or preprocessor input text`.

Comment: [My answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321270/135943) is partially a response/improvement upon this answer.  Very good point about grepping for `ASCII text` to avoid messing up RTFs.

Comment: xenoterracide: You saved my life man ! Just a flag -I and BINGO

Comment: @cas `find .` will also search in subdirectories ! while `file*` will only prints out the current directories' files. must beware

Comment: @ballangddang yep, that's why find has -maxdepth, -mindepth, -depth etc options, and various other options for controlling exactly where and how to search and what to search for.

Answer (score 15):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -I -q . {} \; -print
```

This will find all regular files (`-type f`) in the current directory (or below) that `grep` thinks are non-empty and non-binary.

It uses `grep -I` to distinguish between binary and non-binary files. The `-I` flag and will cause `grep` to exit with a non-zero exit status when it detects that a file is binary. A "binary" file is, according to `grep`, a file that contains character outside the printable ASCII range.

The `-q` option to `grep` will cause it to quit with a zero exit status if the given pattern is found, without emitting any data. The pattern that we use is a single dot, which will match any character.

If the file is found to be non-binary and if it contains at least one character, the name of the file is printed.

If you feel brave, you can plug your `flip -u` into it as well:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -I -q . {} \; -print -exec flip -u {} \;
```

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer didn't find all of them for me.  Here is an example using grep's `-I` to ignore binaries, and ignoring all hidden files...

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec grep -Il '.' {} \; | xargs -L 1 echo
```

Here it is in use in a practical application: dos2unix

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365679/112190

Answer (score 9):

No. There is nothing special about a binary or non-binary file. You can use heuristics like 'contains only characters in 0x01–0x7F', but that'll call text files with non-ASCII characters binary files, and unlucky binary files text files.

Now, once you've ignored that...

### zip files

If its coming from your Windows user as a zip file, the zip format supports marking files as either binary or text in the archive itself. You can use unzip's `-a` option to pay attention to this and convert. Of course, see the first paragraph for why this may not be a good idea (the zip program may have guessed wrong when it made the archive).

zipinfo will tell you which files are binary (b) or text (t) in its zipfile listing.

### other files

The file command will look at a file and try to identify it. In particular, you'll probably find its `-i` (output MIME type) option useful; only convert files with type text/*

Answer (score 8):

A general solution to only process non-binary files in `bash` using `file -b --mime-encoding`:

```bash
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
  [[ "$(file -b --mime-encoding "$file")" = binary ]] &&
    { echo "Skipping   $file."; continue; }

  echo "Processing $file."

  # ...

done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

I contacted the author of the **file** utility and he added a nifty `-00` paramter in version 5.26 (released 2016-04-16, is e.g. in current Arch and Ubuntu 16.10) which prints `file\0result\0` for multiple files fed to it at once, this way you can do e.g.:

```bash
find . -type f -exec file -00 --mime-encoding {} + |
  awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\0"}{if(NR%2)f=$0;else if(!/binary/)print f}' | …
```

(The `awk` part is to filter out every file that isn't non-binary. `ORS` is the output separator.)

Can be also used in a loop of course:

```bash
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do

  echo "Processing $file."

  # ...

done < <(find . -type f -exec file -00 --mime-encoding {} + |
  awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\0"}{if(NR%2)f=$0;else if(!/binary/)print f}')
```

Based of this and the previous I created a little `bash` script for filtering out binary files which utilizes the new method using the `-00` parameter of `file` in newer versions of it and falls back to the previous method on older versions:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Expects files as arguments and returns the ones that do
# not appear to be binary files as a zero-separated list.
#
# USAGE:
#   filter_binary_files.sh [FILES...]
#
# EXAMPLE:
#   find . -type f -mtime +5 -exec ./filter_binary_files.sh {} + | xargs -0 ...
# 

[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && exit

if [[ "$(file -v)" =~ file-([1-9][0-9]|[6-9]|5\.([3-9][0-9]|2[6-9])) ]]; then
  file -00 --mime-encoding -- "$@" |
    awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\0"}{if(NR%2)f=$0;else if(!/binary/)print f}'
else
  for f do
    [[ "$(file -b --mime-encoding -- "$f")" != binary ]] &&
      printf '%s\0' "$f"
  done
fi
```

Or here a more POSIX-y one, but it requires support for `sort -V`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Expects files as arguments and returns the ones that do
# not appear to be binary files as a zero-separated list.
#
# USAGE:
#   filter_binary_files.sh [FILES...]
#
# EXAMPLE:
#   find . -type f -mtime +5 -exec ./filter_binary_files.sh {} + | xargs -0 ...
# 

[ $# -eq 0 ] && exit

if [ "$(printf '%s\n' 'file-5.26' "$(file -v | head -1)" | sort -V)" = \
    'file-5.26' ]; then
  file -00 --mime-encoding -- "$@" |
    awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\0"}{if(NR%2)f=$0;else if(!/binary/)print f}'
else
  for f do
    [ "$(file -b --mime-encoding -- "$f")" != binary ] &&
      printf '%s\0' "$f"
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

[Cas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46290/135943) is good, but it assumes *sane* filenames; in particular it is assumed that filenames will not contain newlines.

There's no good reason to make this assumption here, since it is quite simple (and actually cleaner in my opinion) to handle that case correctly as well:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -q "ASCII text"' sh {} \; -exec flip -u {} \;
```

The `find` command only makes use of [POSIX-specified features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  Using `-exec` to run arbitrary commands as boolean tests is simple, robust (handles odd filenames correctly), and more portable than `-print0`.

In fact, all parts of the command are specified by POSIX except for `flip`.

Note that `file` doesn't guarantee accuracy of the results it returns.  However, in practice grepping for "ASCII text" in its output is quite reliable.

(It might *miss* some text files perhaps, but is very very unlikely to incorrectly identify a binary file as "ASCII text" and mangle it—so we are erring on the side of caution.)

Comment: Argument-less file `calls` can be quite slow, e.g. for videos it will tell you everything about the encoding.

Comment: Also you are assuming no file starts with `-`.

Comment: And I see no reason why you wouldn't just do a single call to `file`, it can take multiple files as arguments.

Comment: @phk, to address your comments: (1) it's good to know the potential slowness, but I see no POSIX way to prevent that; (2) I make *zero* assumptions about file names, as the `find` command will prefix `./` to any filename passed to the shell command; (3) Using `grep` as a test on a single `file` command output at a time is the only POSIX way I can see to guarantee correct handling of filenames that may contain newlines.

Comment: I looked over your final "POSIX-y" solution and I think it's clever—but you assume that `file` supports the `--mime-encoding` flag and the `--` separator, neither of which is [guaranteed by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html).

Comment: Oops, you are right about (2) I forget that every time, unless you use files in the current folder as a parameter to `find` you are save. And concerning what POSIX says about `file` I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using grep alone?

```
grep -rIl "" .
```

- `r` recursive
- `I` all binary files are skipped
- `l` return only filenames
- `""` search for an empty string (= all non-binary files will be found)

Then pipe it with `xargs` to your `flip` command.

Comment: nice and simple solution! please note that using BSD `grep` you cannot avoid to include file-symlinks, while with GNU-`grep`, `-r` excludes and `-R` includes them. With the `find` solution you can control this with the `-type` primary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -Z -L -U '[^         -~]' | xargs -0 -r flip -u
```

Where the argument of `grep '[^         -~]'` is `'[^<tab><space>-~]'`.

If you type it on a shell command line, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> before <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
In an editor, there should be no problem.

- `'[^<tab><space>-~]'` will match any character which is not ASCII text (carriage returns are ignore by `grep`).
- `-L` will print only the filename of files who does not match
- `-Z` will output filenames separated with a null character (for `xargs -0`)

Comment: It's worth noting that with Perl-like Regex `grep -P` (if available) `\t` is available. Alternatively, using locale translation  if the shell supports it: `$'\t'` (`bash` and `zsh` do).

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

The dos2unix command will convert line endings from Windows CRLF to Unix LF, and automatically skip binary files. I apply it recursively using:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Comment: Since `dos2unix` can take multiple filenames as argument, it is much more efficient to do `find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} +`

Answer (score 0):

sudo find / ( -type f -and -path '*/*git*/*' -iname ‘README’ ) -exec grep -liI '100644\|100755' {} \; -exec flip -u {} \;

i.( -type f -and -path '*/*git*/*' -iname ‘README’ ): searches for files within a path containing the name git and file with name README. If you know any specific folder and filename to search for it will be useful.

ii.-exec command runs a command on the file name generated by find

iii.\; indicates end of command

iv.{} is the output of the file/foldername found from the previous find search

v.Multiple commands can be run on subsequently. By appending -exec "command" \; such as with -exec flip -u \;

vii.grep

```
1.-l lists the name of the file
2.-I searches only non-binary files
3.-q quiet output
4.'100644\|100755' searches for either 100644 or 100755 within the file found. if found it then runs flip -u. \| is the or operator for grep.
```

you can clone this test directory and try it out: https://github.com/alphaCTzo7G/stackexchange/tree/master/linux/findSolution204092017

more detailed answer here: https://github.com/alphaCTzo7G/stackexchange/blob/master/linux/findSolution204092017/README.md