# `xargs` with spaces in filenames

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames, xargs

I'm trying to [list only non-image files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46276/finding-all-non-binary-files), searching only in the most recent 500 files. So I run

`ls -t | head -500 | file | grep -v 'image'`

which isn't right: it displays a help message. Changing it to

`ls -t | head -500 | xargs file | grep -v 'image'`

I now sometimes get the output I want, but if the filename has spaces in it—for example `Plutonian\ Nights\ -\ Sun\ Ra.mp3`—then `xargs` will run `file Plutonian`, `file Nights`, etc.

---

How do I either help `xargs` see the spaces, or otherwise accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: In popular `xargs` implementations, the delimiter can be changed, for example to `'\n'`. This is often helpful when the input is not generated by `find`. See `-d` (GNU) and `-E` (OSX)

Comment: @MattBianco `xargs -d '\n\` doesn't appear to recognize newlines properly.

Answer (score 9):

Using `xargs`, it can be done in this way:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -v 'image'
```

But `xargs` is so yesterday. The cool kids use `parallel` today. Using parallel, it would be:

```
find . -type f | parallel file | grep -v 'image'
```

See. No use of -print0 and -0. `parallel` is really smart by itself.

**UPDATE**

For listing only the most recent 500 files, your command would be:

```
ls -1t | head -500 | parallel file {} | grep -v image
```

**Important**

In case your parallel is old and above syntax doesn't work, then install the new version of parallel as explained here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

Use "find" with "-print0" option & pipe the output to "xargs" with "-0" option.

Even though I know (and use) this technique, I see that user @Jens has answered a similar question, where you can find more Details :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/use-xargs-with-filenames-containing-whitespaces

Comment: You got the low-hanging fruit.  How do you search only the most recent 500 files?

Answer (score 1):

I have two crude suggestions that might help.  Neither feels particularly satisfying though, so perhaps something better will come up.

First, use sed to add quotes to everything, so you'd only end up with trouble if there are quotes in the file name like

```
ls -t | head -500 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | xargs file | grep -v 'image'
```

The other is to use the ls to find the 501st most recent then use find to get the newer stuff like

```
find -newer $(ls -t | head -501 | tail -1) -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v image
```

Comment: As long as we're going to parse the output of ls, I believe your first snippet would be improved by replacing newlines with nulls (`tr \\n \\0`) and using `xargs -0`.

Answer (score 1):

For generic advice regarding processing of file names potentially containing spaces, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

The difficulty with what you're trying to do is that there's no nice way to list the N most recent files with standard tools.

The easiest way to do what you're doing here is to use [zsh](http://www.zsh.org) as your shell. It has [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to sort files by date. To run `file` on the 500 most recent files:

```
file *(om[1,500])
```

With the Linux `file` utility, pass the `-i` or `--mime-type` option to get output that's easier to parse. Image files are identified by lines ending with `image/something`.

```
file --mime-type *(om[1,500]) | sed -n 's~: *image/[^ ]*$~~p'
```

If you need to cope with absolutely all file names, including those with a newline in their name, use the `-0` option for null-delimited output. Recent versions of GNU sed can use null bytes as the record delimiter instead of newlines.

```
file --mime-type -- *(om[1,500]) | sed -zn 's~: *image/[^ ]*$~~p'
```

If you don't have zsh, you can use `ls` and cope with file names that contain spaces but not newlines or trailing spaces by passing the `-L1` option to `file`. This invoked `file` on one file at a time, so it's slightly slower.

```
ls -t | head -n 500 | xargs -L1 file --mime-type -- | sed -n 's~: *image/[^ ]*$~~p'
```

Comment: "no nice way to list the N most recent files with standard tools" ... "ls -t | head -n 500"  ???

Comment: @JonathanHartley I mention that in my answer. I also mention its limitations: it only works if your file names don't contain problematic characters.

Comment: Hey. I know you mention it in your answer, that's my point. The first sentence I quote contradicts the second, and in my opinion ought to be deleted. As other answers note, using `ls -print0`, or IFS, is the way to quote spaces or other characters in filenames when using standard tools.

Answer (score -1):

You might try

```
printf "%s\0" $(ls -t | head -500) | xargs -0 file | grep -v image
```

This forces xargs to null-delimit the file name arguments.

Comment: When I try this with a file with spaces in its name (e.g., `Sun Ra`), I get `Sun\0Ra\0`, so this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a set of quotes:

Comment: This will not work; `printf` will consider each space-separated word as an argument. You can test this with `printf "%s\n" $(printf "file #1\nfile2\n")`.

Comment: @dhag: Yeah, I pointed that out 40 minutes ago.

Comment: How about `find . maxdepth 1 -newer "$(ls -t | head -501 | tail -1)" -print0 | xargs -0 file`

Comment: @Doug: If you're going to propose an incremental refinement of Eric's answer, it makes more sense to do it in a comment on Eric's answer — and explain why your answer is better than his.  Also, you missed the `image` part of the question.