# How to apply dos2unix recursively to all the contents of a folder?

Tags: command-line, files

Is there a way to apply the `dos2unix` command so that it runs against all of the files in a folder and it's subfolders? 
`man dos2unix` doesn't show any `-r` or similar options that would make this straight forward?

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How can I run dos2unix on an entire directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11929461/4561887)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix --`

Comment: Don't worry, `dos2unix` skips binaries by default.

Comment: Better said, `dos2unix` *tries* to skip binaries (by default).
I wouldn't trust that it always succeeds.
I'd feel much safer running a separate command for each file extension,
as suggested in
[this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22607).

Answer (score 8):

Using `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
dos2unix **
```

The `globstar` shell option in `bash` enables the use of the `**` glob.  This works just like `*` but matches across `/` in pathnames (hence matching names in subdirectories too).  This would work in a directory containing a moderate number of files in its subdirectories (not many thousands).

In the `zsh` and `yash` shells (with `set -o extended-glob` in `yash`), you would do

```
dos2unix **/*
```

Answer (score 6):

Skipping binaries and hidden files were important for me:

This one worked well for me:

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec grep -Il '.' {} \; | xargs -d '\n' -L 1 dos2unix -k
```

Which translates to: find all non-hidden files recursively in the current directory, then using grep, list all non-binary (-I) non-empty files, then pipe it into xargs (delimited by newlines) one file at a time to dos2unix and keep the original timestamp.

See also:

https://github.com/mdolidon/endlines

Answer (score 5):

You can use find to find all of the files in a directory structure that you want to run through your dos2unix command

```
find /path/to/the/files -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Take a look at the man pages for find, there are a lot of options that you can use to specify what gets evaluated

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Be VERY carefull running this if there is a .git directory anywhere down the file tree...it corrupted my local git repository.

Answer (score 2):

##### How to recursively run `dos2unix` (or any other command) on your desired directory or path using multiple processes

*This answer also implicitly covers "how to use `xargs`".*

I've combined the best from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929475/4561887), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521008/4561887), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759625/4561887), to make my own answer, with 3 separate solutions depending on what you need:

1. Run `dos2unix` (or any other command) on **all files in an entire directory.**

   ```bash
   find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix
   ```

   (NB: do *not* run the above command in a git repository or else it will botch some of the contents of your `.git` dir and make you have to re-clone the directory from scratch! For git directories, you must exclude the `.git` dir. See the solutions below for that.)
2. Run `dos2unix` (or any other command) on **all files, or all checked-in files, in an entire git repository:**

   ```bash
   # A) Use `git ls-files` to find just the files *checked-in* to the repo.
   git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix

   # Or B): use `find`, to find all files in this dir, period, but exclude the
   # `.git` dir so we don't damage the repo. 
   # - See my answer on excluding directories using `find`:
   #   https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887
   find . -not \( -path "./.git" -type d -prune \) -type f -print0 \
       | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix
   ```
3. Run `dos2unix` (or any other command) on **all files, or all checked-in files, in a specified directory or directories within a git repository:**

   ```bash
   # 1. only in this one directory: "path/to/dir1":

   # A) Use `git ls-files` to find just the files checked-in to the repo.
   git ls-files -z -- path/to/dir1 | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix

   # Or B): use `find` to find all files in this repo dir, period.
   find path/to/dir1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix


   # 2. in all 3 of these directories:

   # A) Use `git ls-files` to find just the files checked-in to the repo.
   git ls-files -z -- path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2 path/to/dir3 \
       | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix

   # Or B): use `find` to find all files in these 3 repo dirs, period. Note
   # that by specifying specific folders you are automatically excluding the
   # `.git` dir, which is what you need to do.
   find path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2 path/to/dir3 -type f -print0 \
       | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix
   ```

**Speed:**

Unfortunately, I didn't write down the time it took when I ran it, but I know that the `git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n 50 -P $(nproc) dos2unix` command above converted about [1.5M files in my massive git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684971/4561887) in < 3 minutes. The multi-process command I used above helped *a ton*, allowing my computer's total CPU processing power (consisting of 20 cores) to be as high as 90% utilized overall throughout the duration of the procedure.

**Explanation:**

1. `dos2unix` is the command we are running via `xargs`.
2. The `-print0` in `find`, `-0` in `xargs`, and `-z` in `git ls-files`, all mean to "zero-separate", or "null-separate" file path listings. This way, file paths with special chars and spaces are easily separated by simply looking for the binary zero separating them.
3. `nproc` lists the number of CPU cores your computer has (ex: 8). So, passing `-P $(nproc)` says to spawn as many processes to run the command (`dos2unix` in our case) as we have cores. This way, we attempt to optimize the run-time by spawning one worker process per CPU core.
4. `xargs` allows running individual commands from input piped to it in a stream.
5. `-n 50` says to pass *50 filepaths* to each process spawned to run the command (`dos2unix` in our case); this way, we reduce the overhead of spawning a new `dos2unix` process since we pass it many files at once to process, rather than just one or two or a few.
6. `find .` finds files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`).
7. `git ls-files` lists all files in your git repository.

   1. `--` ends the options passed to `git ls-files` by marking to its parser that no more options to this function will come afterwards. In this way, it knows that everything after `--` is going to be a list of file or folder paths.

##### References:

1. The 3 answers I linked to above.
2. Where I learned about `nproc`: [How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089001/4561887)
3. My answer on [How do I exclude a directory when using `find`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69830768/4561887)

##### See also:

1. [How to find out line-endings in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570574/4561887) - use `file` instead of `dos2unix` in the commands above if you just want to see what the line endings *currently are* for all files in a given directory.
2. My answer: [What are the file limits in Git (number and size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684971/4561887)
3. [GitHub: Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)
4. Another `xargs` example of mine, with the addition of the `-I{}` option to specify argument placement: [How to unzip multiple files at once...using parallel operations (one CPU core per process, with as many processes as you have cores), into output directories with the same names as the zip files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1479490/327339)
5. Sometimes you need to use `bash -c` with `xargs` in order to get proper substitution, such as with `dirname`. See here: [Stack Overflow: Why using dirname in find command gives dots for each match?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158279/4561887)

   1. I used that trick in some of the `xargs` commands to extract .zip files in my repo here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/FatFs. See the readme for those `xargs` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Use  a wildcard. Like this: (If you're in the folder)

```
dos2unix *
```

or if you're outside of the folder do:

```
dos2unix /path/to/folder/*
```

Comment: This doesn't run on sub-folders.